# How can I get information about the Cassandra clusters and datacenters?

Tags: cassandra

How can I get information about the Cassandra clusters, datacenters, and all their details?

Will `system.peers` be sufficient to give all the connected cluster details?

Answer (score 2):

Use `system.local` and `system.peers` both.

In 3 node cluster `system.local` will have data about current node, and `system.peers` will have data about only 2 other nodes

**Note:** `system.local` has only single record.

[Cluster Details](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/use_sys_tab_cluster_t.html)

Comment: querying any particular machine's `peers` table will always give the list all other node always? and how can i query the list of available cluster and the nodes inside it?

Comment: Cluster will have multiple datacenters... clusterName is available only in `local`... peers will have all other nodes in that cluster with datacenter and rack

Answer (score 1):

The direct access to system tables may work, but may not be "portable" between Cassandra versions.  I would recommend to get cluster metadata using driver - it will work with different versions of Cassandra (via [Java driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.4/manual/metadata/), or [Python driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.13/api/cassandra/metadata/)).

P.S. I've got this problem when was extending Cassaforte (driver for Clojure) - after switch to getting metadata via driver, I was able to support all Cassandra versions.